# Raising a custom message for exception in function

Tags: python, exception

MWE of my code distribution:

```
main.py
../func1.py
```

From `main.py` I call `func1.py` with:

```
data_list = [elem1, .., elemN] # Data input.
params = [1., 2., 5.] # Some parameters.

for elem in data_list:
    try:
        func1(elem, params) # Call function.
    except Exception:
        print traceback.format_exc()
```

This way if the function fails for some element, the main code keeps running executing the remaining elements in the list.

I want to insert a custom error message for a given block of `func1`, so I've defined:

```
try:
    # try something
except ValueError:
    raise ValueError('Custom error message.')
```

When a `ValueError` occurs in `func1` the output I get with this, before jumping to the next element in `data_list`,  is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/main.py", line 44, in main
    func1(params)
  File "/func1.py", line 68, func1
    raise ValueError('Custom error message.')
ValueError: Custom error message.
```

Why is the custom error message being printed twice?

Comment: When you `raise` an exception, the full traceback is shown. This includes the line where you raise it with that custom message, so that's why it shows twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception is not raised twice. There can be only one exception "up in the air".

What you are seeing is the whole traceback, an extraordinary help when it comes to finding out why and where your programme crashed, It prints line by line all the frames and ends in the line where the exception was thrown. Therefore you can read your message "again".

If you catch it and print it, you will only see the exception itself. For instance

```
>>> try:
...   raise ValueError('Custom error message.')
... except ValueError as exc:
...   print exc
... 
Custom error message.
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    raise ValueError('Custom error message.')
ValueError: Custom error message.
```

> **"Why is the custom error message being printed twice?"**

this is the last code executed in the Tracedback:

```
    raise ValueError('Custom error message.')
```

This is the actual exception being echoed on your REPL:

```
ValueError: Custom error message.
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not.

You are seeing the top printing because of the traceback

Answer (score 2):

The first time it's printed, the interpreter is quoting the code that raised the exception, namely line 68 of func1.py.
The second time (the last line of your output), it printed the exception message.